# What should be the correct query?

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  employee.name,
  employee.type,
  employee.rate,
  work.overtime,
  work.leaves,
  work.ticket
FROM employee
  LEFT JOIN work ON employee.name = work.name
WHERE work.date BETWEEN :date1 and :date2
HAVING employee.type = :type_emp
```

But it's not working. I want to fetch list of employees of a particular type and their work status should be displayed from date 1 to date 2.

How do I do it?

Comment: what error you getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT
  `employee`.name,
  `employee`.type,
  `employee`.rate,
  `work`.overtime,
  `work`.leaves,
  `work`.ticket
FROM `employee`
  LEFT JOIN `work` ON `employee`.name = `work`.name 
                      AND (`work`.date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2)
WHERE `employee`.type = :type_emp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.type, employee.rate, work.overtime, work.leaves, work.ticket
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN work on employee.name=work.name
  AND work.date between :date1 and :date2 
WHERE employee.type=:type_emp
```

There are 2 problems in the original

- the where clause conditions on the left joined table force the
  equivalent of an inner join, so if there is no work between the dates
  then nothing is listed at all. To fix that move the date filtering to a "join condition" instead of in the where clause
- a having clause is not a substitute for a where clause; a having clause is designed for filtering by aggregated values arising from a group by clause. To fix this simply use the where clause.

There is another potential issue in that between is not the best way to filter for date ranges, instead the following approach is often better BUT :date2 becomes "the next day" from what you use now.

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.type, employee.rate, work.overtime, work.leaves, work.ticket
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN work on employee.name=work.name
  AND work.date >= :date1 AND work.date < :date2 
WHERE employee.type=:type_emp
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  '**having**' with '**and**'  (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

both conditions in where clause will be called using AND operator. Try following

```
SELECT employee.name, employee.type, 
employee.rate, work.overtime, work.leaves, work.ticket 
FROM employee LEFT JOIN work 
ON employee.name=work.name 
WHERE employee.type=:type_emp AND
work.date between :date1 and :date2
```